# Batch file to copy from one drive directory to another by file exclusion list and date modified for files

Tags: batch-file, command

So I was wanting to get together a batch file that would comb through a directory of folders and subfolders with files to copy to a new directory with an exclusion list (or better yet being able to define the beginning name of the file path from where I am starting the copy.

```
@echo off
xcopy /d:10-15-2022 /f /i /s "T:\backup\restricted\builds\source"   "C:\test"    /EXCLUDE:C:\Scripts\exclude2.txt
```

So my assumption here would be that it should copy over everything modified after October 15th with subdirectories to my test location excluding the paths I have in my exclusion list. Sadly this does not seem to work for me though it pulls one location not in the exclusions list and that is it when I know there should be many more.

```
  @echo off
  xcopy /d:10-15-2022 /f /i /s "T:\backup\restricted\builds\source"   "C:\test" /EXCLUDE:C:\Scripts\exclude2.txt
```

gets one folder location out of 30 and then stops.

Exclude file looks a such as a .txt file

```
winner_
winner_1234_reproduction
winner_454_tef_22-22-2022
```

Second attempt now includes used of robocopy but the batch file does not run. It open cmd window then closes it performing no operations.

```
robocopy T:\backup\restricted\builds\source\ D:\test2\ /e/z /copyall /minage:14
```

/XF
winner_bt*
fmts.zip

/XD
"T:\backup\restricted\builds\source\winner__*"
"T:\backup\restricted\builds\source\draw__*"
"T:\backup\restricted\builds\source\pass__*"`/XF

Comment: To highlight code, select it and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Please edit-in your `exclude` file, and provide some examples of directories that behaved in an unwanted manner.

Comment: The `/EXCLUDE` option of `xcopy` is very badly designed, it gives strings that may occur everywhere in the full path of the files. Perhaps you may want to switch to [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)…

Comment: The Exclude list was created from a dir > listoffiles.txt creation that i edited in excel and then put pack into notepad. Text in the exclude file looks like this.
winner_
winner_12345_test
winner_4567rt_235_test

Comment: Please provide some examples of directories that behaved in an unwanted manner. It works according to what I expected on my tests. We need to know what your expectations are to devise a solution to suit. Perhaps you should be aware that `winner_` is sufficient in the `exclude` file as `xcopy` excludes files where **any part** of the absolute filename matches **any line** of the file. As an aside, I also discovered that the exclude file may not be quoted.

Comment: So the exclusion file actually contains names such like the following
win_
Tie_
fmts.zip
So when I run the batch code it opens command window and closes and nothing gets moved or copied. So where might the error be? Can I not mix file types and folder names? since the win_ is the beginning of a folder off the indicated directory.

Comment: Have you **provided some examples of directories that behaved in an unwanted manner** as I requested on October 27th?